# Leaflet SVG icon from JavaScript with image

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet

It's possible to create Leaflet icon from SVG:

```
var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='10' height='10'><path stroke='red' stroke-width='2' fill='none' d='M 0,0 L 10,10 M 10,0 L 0,10 Z'/></svg>";
var svgURL = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + btoa(icon);
var mySVGIcon = L.icon({ iconUrl: svgURL });
```

But when trying to add an image to the SVG (with absolute URL, but it seems that it doesn't working with relative URL either) like this:

```
var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='10' height='10'><img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/abc'/></svg>";
```

The image is not dispayed.

Update:

Not working with valid SVG attributes, too:

```
var icon = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='10' height='10'><image xlink:href='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/abc'/></svg>";
```

Comment: Well, yes. That's because `<img>` is not a valid part of SVG. Try [`<image>` and `xlink:href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag).

Comment: That's right, thanks, my fault when writing the question, but originally I tried with 'image' element with 'xlink:href' attribute, and did not work, too. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You've not defined the xlink namespace. xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"

Comment: You could use https://github.com/hiasinho/Leaflet.vector-markers